# Trying to get last occurrence of string in a file, then get that line and all lines below

Tags: python, operating-system, pathlib

If the last line of a file doesn't include a specific string, I'd like to get the last occurrence of a different sting - then get that line and all lines below.

This is how I am getting the last line. Is there a way to find the LAST occurrence of `alienbutt` and then get that line and all lines below?

````py
from pathlib import Path
import os

logfile = Path(r'\\server\carlsagan\cosmos.log')

with open(logfile, 'rb') as f:
    try:
        f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
        while f.read(1) != b'\n':
            f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR)
    except OSError:
        f.seek(0)
    last_line = f.readline().decode()
if 'Completed' in last_line:
    print('you found it')
else: ```
````

Comment: Is the file small enough that you can just load the whole thing into memory?

Comment: Just a txt file. They'll be like 100kb. But I'm gonna loop through a bunch.

Comment: then loading into memory will be the easiest way...   python easily handles the loops.

Comment: @D.L I was breaking it into simple parts. You often want to break things into simple parts, get that to work, then move onto the next part. I also knew how to do the loop, therefore I didn't waste anyones' time by asking. In the future, you may also want to give examples of what you suggest - dot dot dot ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files are small enough to load into memory, it's much simpler to just turn each file into a list so you can perform simple operations on it without having to scan back and forth on a file object:

```
with open(logfile) as f:
    log = f.readlines()
if 'Completed' in log[-1]:
    print('you found it')
else:
    i = next((
        i for i in range(len(log))[::-1]
        if 'alienbutt' in log[i]
    ), -1)
    if i > -1:
        print(*log[i:], sep='')
    else:
        print("no luck!")
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me test a couple of use cases. Glancing at this - it should work. I'll come back and accept after I test around. Thanks again.